# Can Friedmann equations take in account positron-electron pair formation? How?

Tags: particle-physics, cosmology, pair-production

In Friedmann equations, $\rho$ described matter, radiation or cosmological constant. If it is matter, then $\rho ∝ a^{-3}$ and it is radiation, then $\rho ∝ a^{-4}$. But matter can be described in terms of energy and radiation too. What happens when a $\gamma$ photon becomes a positron-electron pair? How do you take it in account? Or is there something that I am missing? Is it possible that Friedmann equations are only valid in steady state conditions?

Answer (score 2):

The quick answer is to make the distinction not "matter" and "radiation" but rather "non-relativistic stuff" and "relativistic stuff" where we are using the word "relativistic" as a short-hand for "anything whose particles are moving fast, with energy large compared to the rest energy, leading to the equation of state $\rho \propto a^{-4}$".

When applying Friedman equation to the very early universe, one does indeed need to take into account the way what starts as relativistic, high-energy stuff, later becomes slow-moving non-relativistic stuff, thus changing the proportions of stuff of the various types. Neutrinos in particular need to be thought about carefully, but that is not all. As you say, when the universe was hot enough, electrons were relativistic and therefore "radiation-like", and earlier still so were baryons.

Comment: How do you take it into account? Could you show me an worked-out example?

Comment: You just need to let $\rho$ be a more general function of $a$, then you can solve the Friedman equation (typically you will need to solve it numerically)